# Installing libctemplate.so.2 and libzip.so.2 packages on Fedora 16

Tags: linux, fedora

While trying to install a *MySql Workbench* I am getting the following errors:

```
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686 (/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686)
   Requires: libzip.so.2
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686 (/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686)
   Requires: libctemplate.so.2
```

How do I install the packages `libzip.so.2` and `libctemplate.so.2` ? I am using Fedora 16 on 32 bit machine.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in Linux, when something asks for `libfoo.so.N`, the package to install will be `libfoo` which contains `libfoo.so.N`. According to the [fedora packages database](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/), the `libzip` package name is `libzip`. You should be able to install it using yum:

```
yum install libzip
```

I could not find a libctemplate package in fedora's repository but you can download an RPM from [here](http://code.google.com/p/ctemplate/downloads/list?redir=1) which you can then install using `rpm`:

```
rpm -i ctemplate-devel-2.0-1.i386.rpm
```

Comment: `libzip` package installed fine. But I am not sure if ctemplate installed ![I took a snapshot of the terminal.I tried the two rpm. One was ctemplate-devel-2.0-1.i386.rpm and the other one ctemplate-2.0-1.i386.rpm](http://i50.tinypic.com/347tgut.png)

Comment: Looks fine to me. The first command failed because ctemplate-dev needs ctemplate. From what I see in the screenshot, you the proceeded to install ctemplate and then cteplate-dev installed correctly. You can check by running `rpm -q ctemplate`. Assuming everything is OK, try installing mysql again.

Comment: it returns `ctemplate-2.0-1.i386`

Comment: and I get [these](http://i47.tinypic.com/33pc7xd.png) when I try re-installing it

Comment: OK, looks like the devel package (which should contain libctemplate.so.2 was not installed). Is there a specific reason you are not using `yum` to install mysql-workbench? That should be able to deal with all the dependencies automatically.

Comment: Actually I am trying to install fedora 17 package in fedora 16..[I have tried but it doesn't help](http://i46.tinypic.com/o3hwn.png)

Comment: In that case you are bound to get all sorts of dependency and version problems. You would probably be better off installing at least some things from source.

Comment: shall I try to compile and then install the [third download](http://i49.tinypic.com/3590kle.png) using `./configure` commands.. ?

Comment: The problem is that since you are trying to install a package that is newer than your system, it will likely depend on specific versions of libraries that are newer than those available as RPMs for your system. It is those libraries that you may need to install from source. If you install the mysql workbench from source you will run into the same problems as you have with the RPM. Do you _really_ need this specific version of the workbench? Can't you use one that is packaged for fedora 16? Unless you have a specific requirement I would go for the version already packaged for your system.

Comment: I am unable to find `MySql Workbench` for fedora 16